# How to use Where sentence to find username equal to ID in data base?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, where-clause

How to do this:

```
var tmpUser = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
```

This returns me what user is logged in, e.g. it returns, when I am login, the name of username, so Identity is e.g. daniel (username)

Now in some other form, I want to return the ID of this username, so I have start with this:

```
var db = new userDbEntities(); // this is my connection to Database
```

Then:

```
var connectedUser = from user in db.UserTable 
                    select user
```

now here I need WHERE sentence, where I can check if USERNAME is equal to tmpUser, then return the ID of this user in UserTable.

Thanks for any ideas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming **UserName** is the column name in **UserTable** this way will work:

```
string tmpUser = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

using(var db = new userDbEntities())
{

    var connectedUser = (from user in db.UserTable
                        where user.UserName == tmpUser
                        select user).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

or you can simply do using [**SingleOrDefault**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb909919%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

```
string tmpUser = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

using(var db = new userDbEntities())
{
    var connectedUser  = db.UserTable.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.UserName == tmpUser);
}
```

Comment: I have to compere two strings, it shows error Cannot apply operator '==' to operands of type 'string' and 'System.Security.Principal.IIdentity', candidates are: bool==(string, string)

Comment: how to convert to strint?

Comment: honestly, i don't know :(

Comment: oww, I see, but then in string tmpUser ... shows this error: Cannot convert source type 'System.Security.Principal.Iddentity' to target type 'string'

Comment: have you tired this: ``string tmpUser = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name``

Comment: you can also do : ``System.Environment.UserName``

Comment: Ehsan Sajjad you are the best!

Comment: It works with this: string tmpUser = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name

Comment: dont't know who has downvoted your's but i give you upvote..ok..:)

Comment: the one which is in answer?

Comment: yes, First, I have mistake in identify user, your solution: string tmpUser = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name solve it. Then I use the code with ...(from...